# Serving a pdf file in NancyFx

Tags: nancy

I have a developed a Nancy application, I wanted to serve pdf,img,zip files (Download option) by this application.
Any one have idea on this kindly share.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add it as static content. Make sure you setup the bootstrapper correctly if necessary. If you need to do some processing on the file first, check out this 3 part series on serving csv files with Nancy: http://www.philliphaydon.com/2013/05/nancyfx-revisiting-content-negotiation-and-apis-part-3/. Helped me along nicely :-)

Comment: The link that you put up is dead.